# Spectral viewcube in Google CoLab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, spectral-python

Help. I'm trying to get a hypercube in a Google CoLab Notebook using Python 3.

hdc is a 3d numpy array: [x,y,channel]

This code fails:

```
!pip install spectral
from spectral import *
view_cube(hdc_reshaped, bands=[29, 19, 9])
```

This complains about `wx`.

Then I tried:

```
!pip install wxpython
import wx
import wx.glcanvas
!pip install spectral
from spectral import *
view_cube(hdc_reshaped, bands=[29, 19, 9])
```

This still complains about `wx`.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you get an error message when you tried: `pip install wxpython`? I think it's supposed to be: `pip install wxPython`, capitalizing P. Not totally sure though, that's what [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/wxPython/) (the python packaging index) thinks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot use `spectral` or any library that require `wxpython`.

Colab is run in the cloud. It uses Jupyter Notebook interface. It cannot create a normal UI application like wx.

(Unless you try a very difficult hack).